# Unexpected token . in val.toString()

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
_ = require("underscore");
doors = []

function CreateDoors()
{
    _.map( _.range(100), function(val){
    doors.push( { val.toString() : 0 } );
    });
    console.log(doors);
}

CreateDoors();
```

I get an unexpected token error . at val.toString().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get dynamic object keys, you have to use bracket notation

```
var _     = require("underscore"),
    doors = [];

function CreateDoors() {
    _.map( _.range(100), function(val){
        var obj = {};
        obj[val.toString()] = 0;
        doors.push( obj );
    });
    console.log(doors);
}

CreateDoors();
```

Comment: Curious as to why you would continue to use `_.map` only to iterate and throw away its return value. Also, `toString` would seem to be superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `map`, `map` will create the new array for you, so you don't need to declare it yourself and push into it. Just have the callback return the value you want in each position, as in

```
function createDoors() {
  return _.map(_.range(100), function(i) {
    var obj = {};
    obj[i] = 0;
    return obj;
  });
}

var doors = createDoors();
```

A bit more succinctly:

```
function createDoors() {
  return _.map(_.range(100), function(i) {
    return Object.defineProperty({}, i, { value: 0 });
  });
}
```

since `Object.defineProperty` returns the object.

Using ES6 syntax:

```
function createDoors() {
  return _.map(_.range(100), i => Object.defineProperty({}, i, {value: 0}));
}
```

If you have ES6 computed property names available:

```
function createDoors() {
  return _.map(_.range(100), i => ({[i]: 0}));
}
```

If you have ES7 array comprehensions (available in Babel under the appropriate flags):

```
[ for (i of _.range(100)) { [i]: 0 } ]
```

By the way, however you do this, the `toString` is not necessary.